# Prism-MEF: How to export view to certain tab in a tabcontrol using ViewExport

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I don't know if this is possible or not: i have a Navigation Region that is populated
with View_A (via ViewExport) @ program Start up from which i can select an item so its 
details will be displayed in main region. But now i want to put TabControl in the 
Navigation region with many  TabItems each tab will caontain diffrent View: View_A, View_B, ....
so i can use multiple control panels. So can i programmatically assign View_A to Tab_A and
View_B to Tab_B ... so i can switch navigation panels.
Thanks in advance

Note: each view has its view model imported in the code behind

Comment: You should really at least read my answer to your previous question... bcs when you do that you will find the answer to this question... you can let that TabControl be `Region` so after that when you navigate to that region with View_A with HeaderText in ViewModel you have View_A as Tab_A with TabHeaderText... Don't expect us to solve your problems without your contribution...

Comment: btw I would like you to tell me what you mean by saying "Region populated via ViewExport" and what you talk about when you say "navigation panel"?

Comment: @Viktor: i'm truely sorry because i did not check your answer to my previous question but this was because i already found an answer 2 or 3 days ago, but i'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Viktor: for the current question i need to do a different thing, i need when the program start, the navigation region to contain many tabs each tab contain certain view from different module and each view display list of items handled by its module so when i double click an item from any list its details will be displayed in main region.If you can check StockTraderRI quick start program you will find ViewExport attribute used like Export attribute but to assign view for certain region.and by navigation panel i mean the same like navigation region. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: but you should... btw when you find the answer you should accept one of those provided by others or provide your own... it's not polite to leave your question unanswered when you know the answer :)

Comment: @Viktor: you are right but i didn't do this on purpose.